# Pasar parametro a funcion de respuesta del AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema a la hora de gestionar la función de respuesta de una petición AJAX .

En primer lugar os pongo el codigo correspondiente a una peticion :

```html
function cargar_txt() {
 //Inicializa_xhr Obtener la instancia del objeto XMLHttpRequest creando una variable
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    peticion_http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 
 if(peticion_http) 
 {
  peticion_http.onreadystatechange = procesar_txt;
  peticion_http.open("POST", "http://ruta/DatosAProcesar.txt", true);
  peticion_http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  peticion_http.send("");
  // console.log("----Por donde se queda primero----");
  }
}
```

La peticion AJAX llama cada vez que cambia de estado 1XX,2XX... llama a la funcion que se le invoque (en este ejemplo a procesar_txt(), mi problema viene a la hora de pasar paremetros a dicha funcion :

```html
function procesar_txt() {
 
 if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) 
 {
  if(peticion_http.status == 200) 
  {
   var cadena = peticion_http.responseText;   
  }
 }
}
```

Varias preguntas :

- ¿Es realmente necesario esta linea?¿No se podria simplemente llamar con retardo (setTimeOut) a la funcion respuesta ?

`nombre_peticion_http.onreadystatechange = funcion_a_procesar`

- ¿Es posible pasarle parametros a la funcion de respuesta ? ¿Como?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: se puede obtener parametros desde el otro lado que recibe la petición, tu debes mandar algun codigo o flag que desees y sirva de referencia para validar tu peticion ajax, en mi caso acostumbre a poner algo asi: codigo = 'ok_select'....donde este seria mi codigo para validar mi respuesta de ajax...y si no recibo este codigo es xq sucedio algo y fallo la peticion ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es realmente necesario esta linea?¿No se podria simplemente llamar
>   con retardo (setTimeOut) a la funcion respuesta ?

No te recomiendo usar un setTimeOut ya que el tiempo de respuesta de la petición puede variar mucho y el setTimeOut podría ejecutarse antes de tener la respuesta.

> ¿Es posible pasarle parametros a la funcion de respuesta ? ¿Como?

Lo más fácil que se me ocurre es:

```
nombre_peticion_http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    funcion_a_procesar(parametro1, parametro2);
};
```